# How do I limit the user to only selecting one component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code that simply constructs blocks for our products and the selected state allows the component to be selected and unselected. How can I figure out which of these components are selected and limit the user to only selecting one at a time. This is ReactJS code

```
import React from 'react';

export default class singleTile extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.title = this.props.title;
  this.desc = this.props.desc;
  this.svg = this.props.svg;
  this.id = this.props.id;
  this.state = {
    selected: false
  }
}
selectIndustry = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
    if(this.state.selected === false){
      this.setState({
        selected:true
      })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        selected:false
      })
    }

}


render(){
return(
    <div id={this.id} onClick={this.selectIndustry}className={this.state.selected ? 'activated': ''}>
          <div className="icon-container" >
            <div>
              {/*?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?*/}
              { this.props.svg }
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-container">
            <h2>{this.title}</h2>
            <span>{this.desc}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: If your question is answered, you should accept the preferred answer. This helps future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the state of the SingleTile components in the parent component. What i would do is pass two props to the SingleTile components. A onClick prop which accepts a function and a isSelected prop that accepts a boolean. Your parent component would look something like this.

**IndustrySelector.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const tileData = [{ id: 1, title: 'foo' }, { id: 2, title: 'bar' }];

class IndustrySelector extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { selectedIndustry: null };
    }

    selectIndustry(id) {
        this.setState({ selectedIndustry: id });
    }

    isIndustrySelected(id) {
        return id === this.state.selectedIndustry;
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {tileData.map((data, key) => (
            <SingleTile
                key={key}
                {...data}
                onClick={() => this.selectIndustry(data.id)}
                isSelected={this.isIndustrySelected(data.id)}
            />
            ))}
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The way this works is as follows.

**1. Triggering the onClick handler**

When a user clicks on an element in SingleTile which triggers the function from the onClick prop, `this.selectIndustry` in the parent component will be called with the id from the SingleTile component.

> Please note that in this example, the id is remembered through a
>   closure. You could also pass the id as an argument to the function of
>   the onClick prop.

**2. Setting the state in the parent component**

When `this.selectIndustry` is called it changes the selectedIndustry key of the parent component state.

**3. Updating the isSelected values form the SIngleTile components**

React will automatically re-render the SingleTile components when the state of the parent component changes. By calling `this.isIndustrySelected` with the id of the SingleTile component, we compare the id with the id that we have stored in the state. This will thus only be equal for the SingleTile that has been clicked for the last time.

Comment: This was correct. I solved this by passing a function down from the parent into props and binding that to the onchange event

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your parent component code?

It's not so important, but you can save some time by using this ES6 feature:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const {title, desc, svg, id, state} = this.props;
    this.state = {
      selected: false
  }
}
```